# Get queue of iPodMusicPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using iPodMusicPlayer for my MPMusicController.
And I want to get music queue as MPMediaItemCollection.
How can I do that?

In my app, you can select and play music in your music library by MPMediaPickerController. 
Then, if you were playing music by iPod music app, it is interrupted.
After music you selected in my app finished, I want to back to music on iPod music app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't - Apple retains sole control of the inner workings of the ipodmusicplayer

Comment: Then how is it that the 'Ecoute' app can do exactly this? It can retrieve a playlist in the Music app you've created **before** opening the app itself. The only way they were able to do this is by somehow retrieving the current queue. I just want to know if this can be done without using private APIs (which is a possibility for this app).

Comment: No idea @sooper - if you get any insights into this please report back.